# DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Can't overlay lineseries on columnseries

Tags: wpf, charts, overlay, wpftoolkit

I'm using the WPFToolkit v 3.5.4 to overlay two line series on a column series, but the line series are 'pushed' to the left of the column series as seen in the top graph of the image.  All series are of List<KeyValuePair<double, int>> and I've checked the key/value pairs are what I want displayed.

The second graph successfully overlays three LineSeries (using different data) but looks poorly.

Is there a way to mix charting series types (ColumnSeries, LineSeries) on the same chart?

Thanks

Here's the Xaml for the two graphs in the image:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart1" Title="Series1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="449,39,43,0" Height="262">

    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [2]}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    <!-- Remove the legend -->
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>

<chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart2" Title="Series2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="33,330,440,0" Height="262">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [2]}" 
                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

[image: Two Graphs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `LinearAxis` for the first chart, because you put `ColumnSeries` first and they use `CategoryAxis` instead of the correct one.

Here is the code for the first chart:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart1" Title="Series1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="449,39,43,0" Height="262">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
...
```

The code of the second chart is correct, but the chart looks bad because of the data that you use for binding.

Post C# code where you set the `DataContext` property and post what values you use there.